# how to predict the state of an object

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to machine learning and I’d like to explore if the technology can help with my problem.  I have a situation where I am trying to predict the state of a piece of heavy equipment (something loading dirt or hauling dirt) is in based on information about its current status, but more importantly, based on input from other assets around it. For example, let’s focus on a hauling asset and assume there are three states of a hauler: Loading, Hauling, Dumping.  If we take just the Loading state as an example here are some features I would expect to be able to use for the asset itself:
Strut pressure - The more dirt loaded the higher the strut pressure
Engine Idle - The fact the engine is idling might mean it is sitting being loaded
Location - There location (lat/long) of where the asset current resides might indicate a load site
Providing this to a model is good, but it can be significantly more accurate if I can provide details from other assets in the same vicinity, for this example let’s focus on the asset loading the hauling asset. Features I would expect to be important about the loader include :
The proximity of another asset (lat/long) - the fact the loader is close to the hauler (for x period of time).
The sensor values of the loader equipment loading the hauler.  For example, indicating the bucket height of a loader is high just prior to the strut pressure on the hauling has increased.
Payload - The amount of material in the loader itself.

I have a good idea of the features I can use, but I’m not sure how to go about providing these records to an ML algorithm if the number, variety, and context of features from the different assets are not the same.  Each ML example I read provides the exact same feature data in the form of rows (like from a CSV) and most features seem to have a value.  In my scenario, not all assets have the same features, but together they can make the model more accurate.  Further, I’d really like to add additional features that neither asset has, such as some metadata about the geospatial details of when the two assets are in close proximity (ie, they are both in a loading zone) or far apart (traveling down a road classified as a “haul zone”).

So my questions are:

1. Given there can be many assets in a site, do I need a model per asset or one can one model be used?
2. If it’s one model, then is it appropriate to input feature data in rows with sparse rows, or is there another way to input the data?
   If I need a model per asset, then wouldn’t that mean every model has to get all data from all other assets?  Seems like a scalability problem.

Comment: Your problem is ill-defined and you are going to have all kinds of problems because of this, each row should have a value for every variable (or you could imput NA, which creates a whole other set of problems). You could build different models for different assets with different variables and then compare the models - not easy.

Comment: What is ill-defined about my problem?  As I stated, I want to predict the state of an object?  Please suggest what you might need from me for the problem to be more clear?  
Are you stating the problem can't be solved with machine learning technology?  Or are you saying my input has to be thought of differently, which is much different than my problem being ill-defined.